# Find class (not node) starting with "lang"

Tags: javascript, html

In the following HTML example, I would like to get the language used in the `code` element:

```
<div id="editor"><pre><code class="language-js something"></code></pre></div>
```

I can get the class list with the following code:

```
editor = document.getElementById('editor');
let codeNode = editor.querySelector('code[class*="lang"]');
console.log (codeNode.classList);
```

But, now I'm stuck, I don't know how to get the class?

I expect a single string containing the "language-js"

I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: "_I don't know how to isolate the class_" I am not getting what you mean by this. Please elaborate.

Comment: you can get that from jquery very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classList` is a read-only property that returns a live `DOMTokenList` collection of the class attributes of the element. This can then be used to manipulate the class list. But as you want only to get the names of classes on this element you can simply use:

```
codeNode.classList.value
```

DEMO:

```js
editor = document.getElementById('editor');
let codeNode = editor.querySelector('code[class*="lang"]');

let classes = codeNode ? codeNode.classList.value.split(/(\s+)/) : [];
console.log(classes.filter(c => c.startsWith("lang"))[0]);
```

```html
<div id="editor"><pre><code class="language-js something"></code></pre></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get all the classes, not only the class starting with "lang'.

Answer (score 1):

If I got the task correctly, you have just the one element found by its ID, right?
Then you just should take all the classes (getAttribute('class')) and found that one which starts with 'lang'. For that purpose I would use a code like this:

```
document.getElementById('editor').getAttribute('class').split(' ').find(element => element.indexOf('lang')===0)
```

Note that it will return only the fist class starting with the 'lang'.  If you need al of them use reduce() method to build a new array of classes.